# Git Merge issue in Rails Gemfile.LOCK

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

While merging Branch **b2** into **b1** using git:

```
git merge root/b2
```

I get a conflict in my Gemfile.lock

```
       GIT
         remote: git@git.abc.com:Proj1/lib1.git
      <<<<<<< HEAD
         revision: w6efra4fr643a3bc07497rdadc1fc0baf9cc736f
         branch: b1
      =======
         revision: 2b38d19b924724667aed675b31fc6649012a8141
         branch: b2
      >>>>>>> root/b2
         specs:
           lib1 (0.2.1)
             active_patch (>= 0.0.2)
```

I am new to rails so not sure how to resolve this conflict. Any help here ?

Comment: You'll have to look at the difference between branches `b1` and `b2` to decide how to resolve this merge.

Comment: delete your Gemfile.lock (rm -rf Gemfile.lock) then bundle install and commit it. :)

Comment: Oh, I can just delete the Gemfile.lock, run bundle install to generate a new one and commit it, correct ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are committing your Gemfile.lock, then deleting it and then running bundle install is worst thing you want with your application.

Reason being

1. In case your Gemfile has a gem witout its version, it is likely to be get updated to latest version.

   `gem 'mysql'`   ## will update to 0.3.16

   `gem 'mysql', '3.0.14'` ## no need to worry, will remain same
2. Many gem use pesimistic version of other gem while dependencies.( eg '~> {ver}'). Creating a new Gemfile.lock will certainly update these pessimistic dependencies.

Although that might, might not break your application. But at least gem should only be updated, when you want it to.

Comming back to your problem, you can use following git merge stratergies to ensure what changes you want to keep

```
`git merge -Xours b2` This will keep changes from file version of b1 branch in case of conflict
`git merge -Xtheirs b2` This will keep changes from file version of b2 branch in case of conflict
```

If you are not sure which one you want, use any and update gem to its latest git commit

```
`bundle update --source lib1`
```